# bootstrap accordion with two more/less link

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I'm trying to create a collapsible panel with the possibility to click on two point to expand/collapse it, on the panel title and on the bottom right text.

What I did so far is this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel1">Title Panel 1</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="panel1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Contents panel 1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="expandPanel">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel1">Expand</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel2">Title Panel 2</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="panel2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Contents panel 2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="expandPanel">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel2">Expand</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel3">Title Panel 3</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="panel3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Contents panel 3
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="expandPanel">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel3">Expand</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $active = $('#accordion .panel-collapse.in').prev().addClass('active');
    $active.find('a').append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus pull-right"></span>');
    $('#accordion .panel-heading').not($active).find('a').prepend('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right"></span>');
    $('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e)
    {
        $('#accordion .panel-heading.active').removeClass('active').find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
        $(e.target).prev().addClass('active').find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
    });
    $('#accordion').on('hide.bs.collapse', function (e)
    {
        $(e.target).prev().removeClass('active').find('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-minus').addClass('glyphicon-plus');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f908rx8v/1/

I'm stuck there.

I would like to move the plus/minus image from the panel title to the bottom right and the text "Expand" should follow the rule; show "Expand" when the panel isn't expanded and "Collapse" when it's expanded.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to hide expand link when it's parent is expanded?

Answer (score 0):

I placed the glyphicons initially inside .expandPanel a, so they will appear on the bottom right, and edited your JS a little to make them udpate as well as the text on the left side:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {

    $('.panel-collapse').on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
      var expandPanel = $(this).next('.expandPanel');

      expandPanel
        .find('.toggle-text').text('Expand');

      expandPanel
        .find('.glyphicon')
          .removeClass('glyphicon-minus')
          .addClass('glyphicon-plus');
    });

    $('.panel-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
      var expandPanel = $(this).next('.expandPanel');

      expandPanel
        .find('.toggle-text').text('Collapse');

      expandPanel
        .find('.glyphicon')
          .removeClass('glyphicon-plus')
          .addClass('glyphicon-minus');
    });


});
```

```html
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel1">Title Panel 1</a>
                  </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="panel1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                      Contents panel 1
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="expandPanel">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel2">
                    <span class="toggle-text">Collapse</span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus pull-right"></span>
                  </a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel2">Title Panel 2</a>
                  </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="panel2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                      Contents panel 2
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="expandPanel">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel2">
                    <span class="toggle-text">Expand</span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right"></span>
                  </a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel3">Title Panel 3</a>
                  </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="panel3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                      Contents panel 3
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="expandPanel">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel3">
                    <span class="toggle-text">Expand</span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right"></span>
                  </a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I'm looking for!


Thank you very much @Chris Wacker!!

Comment: Can I ask you one more thing?


Would be possible to scroll to the correspondent <div class="panel panel-default"> when someone click on the title or on the Expand/Collapse text?


Thanks!